# Complex mathematical question. Any help is much appreciated.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know it's a little long, but I can't work any of these questions out for the life of me. Help appreciated!

A researcher is interested in the buying behaviour (an indicator of demand) of a selected
group of party pill users. In a controlled experiment, a new legalised party pill is put on
to the market. Based on previous data, the researcher suggests the following demand
model: D(t) = 100 - 95 (3/5)t t is measured in the number of weeks it has been on the
market, and D(t) represents the percentage of the selected group wanting to buy the
party pill after t weeks (D(t) = 87, means 87% of the selected group).

a) Practically interpret what the model suggests about D(t) when t = 0.

b) How many days after the party pill is released does the model D(t) suggest that the
demand for the party pill will first exceed 50% of the selected group?

c) After a short time though, the researcher has to revise his model because real data
received from the outlet stores suggests that approximately 11 hours after the party
pill went on the market, 50% of the selected group had purchased it. He revises his
model to D(t) = 100 - 95(A)t. Find A and hence write the new model.

Comment: When you write D(t)=100-95(3=5)t, since when is $3=5$? Maybe you misstyped ;) ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that mistake out. Yes, I did mistype and have now corrected it :)

Answer (score 0):

You know that
 \begin{align}
D(t) = 100- 95 \cdot \Bigl(\frac{3}{5}\Bigr)^t
\end{align}
So for your first question $D(t=0)= 100-95\cdot \Bigl(\frac{3}{5}\Bigr)^0 = 100-95\cdot 1 = 5$
This means that at the moment you launch the product already $5\%$ want to buy it.

For the second question we want to know when $D(t)=50$. Note that the model works with $t$ in weeks but you ask for days. We first solve $D(t)=50$

\begin{align}
&D(t) = 100- 95 \cdot \Bigl(\frac{3}{5}\Bigr)^t = 50 \\
\Leftrightarrow&  95 \cdot \Bigl(\frac{3}{5}\Bigr)^t = 100-50 = 50 \\
\Leftrightarrow& \Bigl(\frac{3}{5}\Bigr)^t=\frac{50}{95}
\end{align}
Do you know how to solve this for $t$? This will give you the result in weeks.

For your last question you have a new model  $D_{new}(t) =100-95\cdot A^t$ and need to solve $D_{new}(\frac{11}{24\cdot 7}) = 50$ for $A$. Again you ask for hours, but your model is in weeks, therefore the $\frac{11}{24\cdot 7}$.

Comment: Hi, macydamin. Thank you for replying to my comment. I understand the first question you answered but I'm having a little difficulty in understanding both b and c. Would you be able to flesh these two out again? Many thanks.

Comment: The above answer includes the part for b). Or is there something you didn't understand?

Comment: Would you be able to answer this one last question for me, please?

Give a practical interpretation of the asymptotic behavior for the function D(t) of your new model.

My model is: D(t)=100−95(0.00005529327)^t

Comment: Well, if you let $t \rightarrow \infty$ the term $(0.0000055..)^t$ reaches $0$, thus $D(t \rightarrow \infty) = 100$.